# Nonlinear-System

Tags: logarithms, contest-math, nonlinear-system

Solve the following system:

\begin{align*}
4^{-x} + 27^{-y} &= \frac{5}{6} \\
27^y - 4^x &\leq 1 \\
\log_{27}(y) - \log_{4}(x) &\geq \frac{1}{6}
\end{align*}

Source: Romanian National Olympiad 1999

I tried to take the logarithm in base ten for the first 2 and denoted lg(x)=a and lg(y)=b, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Idea: Let $a=27^y$ and $b=4^x$...

Comment: @nonuser I have tried that substitution but I don’t know how to continue and how to use it in the last inequality. I think that x=1/2 and y=1/3. Could you help me please in writing the proof? Thank you in advance

Comment: You would have to edit those details in your question or else this post would get closed soon.

Answer (score 1):

Using the first two statements, we have
$$\frac56=4^{-x}+27^{-y}\geqslant \frac1{4^x}+\frac1{4^x+1} \implies 4^x\geqslant 2$$
Then using the last one, we have
$$\log_{27}y\geqslant \log_4x+\frac16\geqslant \log_4(\log_42)+\frac16=-\frac13 \implies 27^y\geqslant 3$$
Hence
$$\frac56=\frac1{4^x}+\frac1{27^y}\leqslant \frac12+\frac13=\frac56$$
compels all the inequalities above to become equalities, so $(x,y)=(\frac12, \frac13)$.